# SQLite statement logic

Tags: javascript, sqlite, conditional-statements

I have a statement like so:

```
transaction.executeSql('SELECT item1, item2 FROM table WHERE ...)
```

is it possible to do something like the following:

1. If item1 is not null and item2 is null, only select item1
2. If item1 is null and item2 is not null, only select item2
3. If item1 and item2 are null, don't select either of them
4. If item1 and item2 are not null, select both of them

is there a way to satisfy all four of these conditions in one SELECT statement?  I have been thinking about it, but I feel like I have to do two separate SELECT statements.  I've tried to figure out how to do it with AND and OR but no luck.  This is mostly for personal interest, as I could do it separately, but nevertheless I'd appreciate anyone's help.

Comment: No need for two queries either way. Just select both fields and filter out `null`s afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT queries must return a fixed number of columns, so the only way to do this is to use a single column and to return a varying number of records:

```
SELECT item1 FROM MyTable WHERE item1 IS NOT NULL AND ...
AND
SELECT item2 FROM MyTable WHERE item2 IS NOT NULL AND ...
```